# Should POSIX sticky bit deny appending by root?

Tags: permissions, root, sticky

POSIX directory permissions include the "sticky" bit (`S_ISVTX`) which is [described](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) as limiting deletion or renaming to just the owner of a file, or to root. This is often used for directories such as `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` which may have permissions `drwxrwxrwt` to allow all users to create temporary files, but prevent other non-root users from deleting those files.

My question is about root's permission to *modify* files created by ordinary users within directories marked with the sticky bit.

Suppose, an ordinary user creates a file in a sticky-bit protected `/var/tmp` (which is on a local, non-NFS filesystem, with no SELinux restrictions):

```
echo "something" > /var/tmp/somefile
```

but then root tries to append to this file:

```
echo "else" >> /var/tmp/somefile
```

When I try this on some Linux systems (e.g. Debian-11, ArchLinux) this produces a `bash: /var/tmp/somefile: Permission denied` error. This seems an unexpected restriction on the powers of the superuser to change files in the local filesystem. Other flavours of Linux (e.g. Debian-10, Debian-9, Fedora-35) do not seem to have this restriction, despite no obvious differences in filesystem setup.

I've not been able to find any documentation that suggests that the sticky bit should prevent root from modifying such a file. For example, the POSIX documentation for [sys/stat.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) which underpins `chmod`, says very little about behaviour other than deletion of sticky-protected files.

Can anyone point me towards any official documentation of how the sticky bit should behave when the superuser tries to modify a file in a directory marked with the sticky bit, or what system settings influence this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer found

The behavior you are showing seems to depend on the `fs.protected_regular` Linux kernel parameter, introduced along with `fs.protected_fifos` by [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=30aba6656f61ed44cba445a3c0d38b296fa9e8f5), with the aim to fix security vulnerabilities.

### Solution:

`sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0`

### Resources:

> Since it is a patch, it probably won't be documented in more detail.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250974/user-root-cant-write-to-file-in-tmp-owned-by-someone-else-in-20-04-but-can-in/1251030#1251030
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503111/group-permissions-for-root-not-working-in-tmp

Comment: Perhaps it's obvious that, if even root is affected, so is a regular user trying to write to someone else's file, for which they appear to have write permission, where the sticky bit is in effect